# jQuery .click - How to check for div click, image click or <td> click

Tags: jquery

Im using http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com's expand a row jQuery code [(Link to the creator's site)](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/examples/expandable-rows/) and it works great except I have links in my table. When a link in the table is clicked it expands the row. It does go to the link but it might give the user the impression that they mis-clicked the link so I would rather have them click the arrow image only. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#blue_table_expand_small_spacing tr:odd").addClass("odd");
                $("#blue_table_expand_small_spacing tr:not(.odd)").hide();
                $("#blue_table_expand_small_spacing tr:first-child").show();

                $("#blue_table_expand_small_spacing tr.odd").click(function(){
                    $(this).next("tr").toggle();
                    $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
                });
                //$("#blue_table_expand_small_spacing").jExpand();
            });
    </script>
```

This is the table html - not complete of course. This div has an arrow image in it , a .png:

```
<td class="clicked_arrow"><div class="arrow"></div></td>
```

If I change the javascript to the following the arrow flips but the next row no longer expands.

```
$("#blue_table_expand_small_spacing tr.odd td.clicked_arrow").click(function(){
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely because when you add the td.clicked_arrow to your selector, you're going another step down in the DOM.  Which means your call to .next("tr") finds nothing, because its not on the same level.  You first need to go back up to the parent TR and then find the .next("tr").

Try changing:

```
$(this).next("tr").toggle();
```

to:

```
$(this).closest("tr").next("tr").toggle();
```

the closest finds the closest parent that matches the selector.

Comment: Awsome! Thanks that was it! Thanks for the clear explanation as to what was happening with the DOM as well!